# PHP Email Importer (from CSV, Gmail, Outlook, etc)

Tags: php, email, csv, import, import-contacts

I'm looking for a PHP solution that will allow me to import an email contact list (along with other information such as name, address, phone, etc) from a CSV spreadsheet, Gmail, Outlook, and other major email providers. I'm not only looking for free solutions, so I'd be willing to pay if it's a pretty comprehensive import tool. Thanks for the help all.

Comment: Are you looking for all CSV, gmail, outlook or just one of em? and what do you mean import? Please make your question more clear. You can easily import a CSV into a mysql database using delimiters. But I am not sure thats what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://www.openinviter.com